# How to get all posts in gallery post format template

Tags: posts, loop, post-thumbnails, get-posts, post-formats

I'm doing a WordPress theme, and I get stuck on one thing. As you know, the post-format in WordPress has different types of formats, I did all the types except the gallery. I get the category page showing the post with the feature image as you can see here www.paperbleu.com but it only shows the one (the first) post.

The post that is missing: http://paperbleu.com/2016/10/candeeiro-tulipa/

```
<?php /* How to display posts of the Gallery format. The gallery category is the old way. */ ?>

<?php if (( function_exists('get_post_format') && 'gallery' == get_post_format($post->ID) ) || in_category(_x('gallery', 'gallery category slug', 'twentyten'))) : ?>
    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

        <?php if (post_password_required()) : ?>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php else : ?>
            <?php
            $images = twentyten_get_gallery_images();
            if ($images) :
                $total_images = count($images);
                $image = reset($images);
                ?>

                <div class=""> 
                    <?php
                    $posts = get_posts(array('posts_per_page' => 30));
                    foreach ($posts as $_post) {
                        if (has_post_thumbnail($_post->ID)) {
                            echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($_post->ID) . '" title="' . esc_attr($_post->post_title) . '">';
                            echo get_the_post_thumbnail($_post->ID, 'medium');
                            echo '</a>';
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>

            <?php endif; // end twentyten_get_gallery_images() check ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
        <!-- .entry-content -->

        <div class="entry-utility">
    <?php if (function_exists('get_post_format') && 'gallery' == get_post_format($post->ID)) : ?>
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_post_format_link('gallery')); ?>" title="<?php esc_attr_e('View Galleries', 'twentyten'); ?>"><?php _e('More Galleries', 'twentyten'); ?></a>
                <span class="meta-sep">|</span>
    <?php elseif ($gallery = get_term_by('slug', _x('gallery', 'gallery category slug', 'twentyten'), 'category') && in_category($gallery->term_id)) : ?>
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_category_link($gallery)); ?>" title="<?php esc_attr_e('View posts in the Gallery category', 'twentyten'); ?>"><?php _e('More Galleries', 'twentyten'); ?></a>
                <span class="meta-sep">|</span>
            <?php endif; ?>
    <?php edit_post_link(__('Edit', 'twentyten'), '<span class="meta-sep">|</span> <span class="edit-link">', '</span>'); ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-utility -->
    </div><!-- #post-## -->
```

Comment: I see that post you mention on the homepage as well (twice, actually)

Comment: @cjbj Yes. I found that it was missing the "feature image" for that post. When I chose a feature image the post appeared on the page. But now appears twice each post.